# Ant: Unable to get Ant to copy properties file to classes directory

Tags: java, ant, build, war

I have a project which I can build and deploy correctly using Ant

I want to build a war file to deploy the project.

I can get everything working except I cannot get the properties file to appear in the classes directory.

My properties file is located here: /h/a/A/I/S/src/Serv/log4j.properties

This is the war section of my build file:

```
<war destfile="Int.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
     <lib dir="${libDir}" />

     <classes dir="${outputDir}" includes="/h/a/A/I/S/src/Serv/log4j.properties"/>
     <classes dir="${outputDir}" />

   </war>
```

I have read the previously asked similar questions here and added the second classes element here which includes the properties file but it did'nt worked for me, any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, path of .properties file will be assumed by ant as "${outputDir}/h/a/A/I/S/src/Serv/log4j.properties" which is an invalid path in your project..
Try using copy task for moving .properties file to '${outputDir}' directory and then perform war packaging.

Comment: thank you sooooo much ....i almost fainted working on this issue :D ....it worked fine .....i have a issue with these paths in ant's build.xml ......many places i have given the absolute path to avoid such things but thats not a good way to do so .... Could you suggest if we can store all absolute paths in another file and that can be read by build.xml ....is it a good way or any other way .....I am new to this, tx fr help:) ....